# How to load custom libraries in flume first

Tags: java, hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I have written a sink to write directly to cassandra database. I have also provided all the necessary cassandra dependencies to the flume-agent.
But while executing, i am getting a error

```
015-04-30 00:53:25,736 (conf-file-poller-0) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:149)] Unhandled error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.newConcurrentHashSet()Ljava/util/Set;
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$ConnectionReaper.<init>(Cluster.java:2065)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.<init>(Cluster.java:1163)
```

Now this is because cassandra jars require guava-16.0.1.jar. I have provided that, but i see flume picks up guava-11.X.X.jar which is shipped by default in CDH5.

Like job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first", "true");

How can i tell flume to pick up my jars first

Answer (score 1):

Did you already installed your new sink (packaged as .jar file) under `[APACHE_FLUME_HOME]/plugins.d/mynewsink/lib`? Related dependencies should be under `[APACHE_FLUME_HOME]/plugins.d/mynewsink/libext`.

You can also package the .jar file with dependencies instead of putting them into `libext`.

Comment: FLUME_HOME=/usr/lib/flume-ng
I have put the third party libs & my lib in FLUME_HOME/lib

My command

#flume-ng agent \   --conf-file mysql-to-cassandra.properties \   --name MyAgent \   --conf $FLUME_HOME/conf \   -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console

Comment: Instead of putting your new sink into `[FLUME_HOME]/lib`, try to install it under `[FLUME_HOME]/plugins.d` as proposed. Related doc: https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#installing-third-party-plugins

Comment: Interesting this didn't help as the /lib took priority over /plugins.d --->
usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/usr/lib/flume-ng/conf:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/*:/usr/lib/flume-ng/plugins.d/mysqltocassandra/lib/*:/usr/lib/flume-ng/plugins.d/mysqltocassandra/libext/*:/etc/hadoop/conf:
---->
But i did a workaround, i changed permission of guava-11.X.X to 000 and it works for me.
Wonder if its a bug in flume. But thanks for your help